# Cannot resolve keyword 'get_album_detail' into field

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-orm, django-managers

Am trying to create a search field that can get the artist name and the name of the song, but am getting an error saying "Cannot resolve keyword 'get_full_album_detail' into field." once i try to query from 'get_album_detail'.

```
 class Artist(models.Model):
    user            =   models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    username        =   models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, unique=True)



class Album(models.Model):
        artist      =   models.ForeignKey(Artist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        name        =   models.CharField(max_length=120)

    @property
    def get_album_detail(self):
        return str(self.artist.username) + " - " + str(self.name)



   ### CUSTOM MODEL MANAGER
class SongQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def search(self, query = None):
        qs = self
        if query is not None:
            or_lookup = (Q(get_album_detail__icontains=query)|
                Q(slug__icontains=query)
                #Q(artist__user__icontains=query)
                )
            qs = qs.filter(or_lookup).distinct()
        return qs

## SEARCH VIEW
class AlbumSearch(ListView):
    template_name   =   'search/song_search.html'
    paginate_by     =   15  

    def get_queryset(self):
        request =   self.request
        query = request.GET.get('q', None)
        if query is not None:
            song_result   =   Song.objects.search(query=query)
            return song_result
```

Comment: `get_album_detail` is *not* a field. It is not stored in the database, hence you can not query on this.

Answer (score 2):

`get_album_detail` is *not* a field, it is a property. This thus means that it is determined at the Django/Python layer, and thus the database can not filter on it, since the Django/Python layer is not known by the database.

You can use [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) to "derive" the field in the query and then filter on it. In this case, we can use [**`Concat`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/database-functions/#concat):

```
from django.db.models import Value
from django.db.models.functions import Concat

# …

def search(self, query = None):
    qs = self
    if query is not None:
        or_lookup = (
            Q(album_detail__icontains=query) |
            Q(slug__icontains=query)    
        )
        qs = qs.annotate(
            album_detail=Concat('artist__username', Value(' - '), 'name')
        ).filter(or_lookup).distinct()
    return qs
```

Comment: While this is technically correct, it's not advised. The computed string is for the purpose of querying identical to the combination of username and name. Those fields can be indexed. This concat can never be indexed. In fact, I would prefer to denormalize into a lookup model over doing concats like this. Concat should be used when at least one component is provided as search query.

Comment: @Melvyn: well if the query spans is `foo - bar`, then this can mean multiple things: that `foo` is the artist and `bar` the name, or that the artist somehow has `foo - bar`. It is indeed not a good idea to search with `__icontains` on multiple fields. This mainly because searching, even on a prefix-tree is computationally expensive. In order to match elements, one should use technology like for example elasticsearch that generates fragments, and also searches with a "fuzzy" FSM that allows typo's for example.

Comment: I mean, you can split the lookup on ' - ', then `filter(artist__username=split[0], name=split[1])` and build the annotation after the filtering. That is - if you still need the annotation and I think you might not need it any more.

Comment: @Melvyn: no, in case you this by splitting, it should be `.filter(artist__username__iendswith=split[0], name__istartswith=split[1])`, especially the `__endswith` will, unless there are some advanced indexing mechanisms in place like a suffix tree, result in performance degradation. It is also from a software design point of view, very hard to get the specifics exactly correct if the case will be more complex.

Comment: Melvyn: but actually "searching" on the database is not a good idea in the first place. Databases are not constructed to perform search like a search engine does this. This is more to retrieve, join, aggregate, and store items. One needs more advanced techniques, like *n*-grams to implement good search. It is a bit sad that the Django ocumentation does not mention much about it, it never really says `__icontains` is a good way to search, but neither does it say how to do search effectively.

Comment: I would think the concat to be slower, but we would measure that. And I would still prefer offloading to a lookup table (poor man's Elastic index) or indeed a more specialized service.

Comment: @Melvyn: well likely `Concat` is indeed slower, but not that much. If it has to do a "full scan" over the table, then the bottleneck will be I/O to retrieve the records, not calculating a field or filtering on it.